# Running Custom Textsecure (signal) Server Locally on Windows 10

Tags: java, signals, dropwizard, instant-messaging

I need to remove error in setting up of Signal server on my desktop ___Topic - Setting up of Signal Server on windows.
Post followed -

1. [Run custom TextSecure (Signal) server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699970/run-custom-textsecure-signal-server)
2. http://debabhishek.com/writes/Installing-and-Running-TextSecure-Signal-Server-on-Windows/

I am using ref .yml file template from github resources  for signal.

When trying to - RUn

```
java -jar target/TextSecureServer-1.88.jar accountdb migrate config/textsecure.yml
```

I get error - >

> io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException:
>   config/textsecure.yml has an error:   * Failed to parse configuration
>   at: turn.uris.[0]; Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String`
>   out of START_OBJECT token  at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
>   (through reference chain:
>   org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.WhisperServerConfiguration["turn"]->org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.configuration.TurnConfiguration["uris"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
>
> at io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException$Builder.build(ConfigurationParsingException.java:279)
>           at io

...

My textsecure.yml file is -

```
twilio: # Twilio gateway configuration
  accountId: MYID
  accountToken: MYTOKEN
  numbers: # Numbers allocated in Twilio
    -

      +MYNO

  messagingServicesId: 
  localDomain:  http://localhost/
  # Domain Twilio can connect back to for calls. Should be domain of your service.

push:
  queueSize: 10000
  # Size of push pending queue


turn: # TURN server configuration
  secret:  # TURN server secret
  uris:
    - stun: http://localhost:80
    - stun: http://localhost:443
    - turn: http://localhost:443?transport=udp
    - turn: http://localturn4signal:80?transport=udp

cache: # Redis server configuration for cache cluster
  url: redis://12.12.12.1:6379/1
  replicaUrls: redis://12.12.12.1:6379/2

directory: # Redis server configuration for directory cluster
  url: redis://12.12.12.1:6379/3
  replicaUrls: redis://12.12.12.1:6379/4

messageCache: # Redis server configuration for message store cache
  url: redis://12.12.12.1:6379/5
  replicaUrls: redis://12.12.12.1:6379/6

messageStore: # Postgresql database configuration for message store
  driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver
  user: postgres
  password: ""
  url:   "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/messagedb"

attachments: # AWS S3 configuration
  accessKey: MyKey
  accessSecret: MySecret
  bucket: MuBucket1

profiles: # AWS S3 configuration
  accessKey:   MYKEY2
  accessSecret: MySectret2
  bucket: MyBucket2
  #region:

database: # Postgresql database configuration
  driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver
  user: "postgres"
  password: ""
  url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/accountsdb"

apn: # Apple Push Notifications configuration
  bundleId:  
  pushCertificate:  
  pushKey:  

gcm: # GCM Configuration
  senderId: MYID
  apiKey: MYKEY
```

Can some one please help to remove the error

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `http://` and spaces.
You probably are looking for:

```
turn: # TURN server configuration
secret:
uris:
  - stun:127.0.0.1:80
  - stun:127.0.0.1:443
  - turn:127.0.0.1:80?transport=udp
  - turn:127.0.0.1:443?transport=udp
```

For more details, see the forum-thread:  https://community.signalusers.org/t/seeting-up-of-new-signal-server-instance-on-windows-10/4032/4

Comment: Thanks Cleber,  It worked .. But I have some redis server error I am trying to resolve it by putting ""

Comment: Some fields from config file is missing, you should see the source from application server to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
turn: # TURN server configuration
  secret: 121654fjdfgdyesdfgfhgh # TURN server secret
  uris:
    - stun:yourdomain:80 #fake
    - stun:yourdomain.com:443 #fake
    - turn:yourdomain:443?transport=udp #fake
    - turn:etc.com:80?transport=udp #fake
```

This is the configuration working for me.