# Run Custom Signal Server: no main manifest

Tags: java, maven, github, server, jar

I followed the instructions in this question, [Run Custom Signal Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699970/run-custom-textsecure-signal-server?rq=4), to run a custom version of the Signal protocol. However, even basic instructions failed when the jar compiled without a main manifest attribute. I tried a number of things but the protocol specifications do not seem to provide an answer.

```bash
git clone https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Server.git
cd Signal-Server
cp service/config/sample.yml service/config/config.yml
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Pexclude-abusive-message-filter
java -jar service/target/TextSecureServer-9.77.1-dirty-SNAPSHOT.jar server service/config/config.yml
```

Error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in service/target/TextSecureServer-9.77.1-dirty-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the way to execute it? Doesn't look to be an executable jar

Comment: Ok, how do you execute the server?

Comment: check on https://github.com/JJTofflemire/Signal-Server README.md